# How can I change the appearance of the status bar?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, statusbar

I'm trying to change te appearance of here status bar based on Userdefaults, who detect if the user has the mode turned on, but using `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` doesn't work. I set the default status bar as Light. 
This is the code that I'm currently using:

```
var darkModeOn: Bool! 

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let isDarkMode = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isDarkMode")  // Retrieve the state

    if isDarkMode == false{

        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isDarkMode")
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    }else{

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isDarkMode")
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 35/255, green: 35/255, blue: 35/255, alpha: 1)


    }

}
```

And I've tried to use

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return darkModeOn ? .lightContent : .default
}
```

but is shows only the light status bar

Comment: In your Info.plist file have you set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to YES?

Comment: In the info.plist View controller-based status bar appearance is set to No

Answer (score 1):

In Info.plist set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to YES. If it's set to NO then it's gonna apply the default value to all view controllers.

Once it's set to yes use this to override the appearance in each view controller:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
    //or return .default
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

1. In Info.plist, set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES`
2. Override `preferredStatusBarStyle`:

   `override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
       return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isDarkMode") ? .lightContent : .default
   }`

BUT, if this view controller is embed in a navigation controller, the override will be ignored, so you must use this code instead:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isDarkMode") ? .black : .default
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Strangely it seems that the UI does not update. If I launch the app, the status bar style is set on what I've set inside the project settings. If I set to default is always black, If is set to lightContent is always white, and I set the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to Yes

Comment: Is this view controller is in navigation controller stack? I mean you "push" it or "present" it? @GiovanniFilippini

Comment: The main UI yes, but the settings page no. Here's an image of my Storyboard: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jrl39ncnmbup5o1/Schermata%202019-02-11%20alle%2018.51.25.png?dl=0

Comment: I updated my answer. If that still doesn't work, then I don't know why (sorry :( ). Also be certain with your value in UserDefault, use setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() when you want to update bar style in runtime. Good luck!